# werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError While trying to get .csv file from a GET request using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to get a .csv file from a form, get it on my server, open it and treat the nunmers to return the valid ones, but when I try to open the file from the request I get "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError"

My html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/api/listtels" method="get">
      <label for="tels">file:</label>
      <input name="tels" type="file" id="tels"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my python code is this:

```
import flask
import csv
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/api/listtels', methods=['GET'])
def ltels():

    tels = "ERROR" 
    ret = "ERROR"
    if 'tels' in request.args:
        tels = request.files['tels']
        ret = "tel\n"
    else:
        return("\'tels\' arg is needed")
    with open(tels, encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
        next(rows, None)
        for row in rows:
            tel = row[0]
            tel = str(''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, tel)))
            if len(tel) == 11:
                ret = ret + tel + "\n"
            elif len(tel) == 13:
                ret = ret + "+" + tel + "\n"
    return (ret)


app.run()
```

It's been 3 days since I started to use Python and Flask, so plz, no judgment :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flask `request.files` machinery assumes that the request is going to be a POST, because it isn't possible to upload a file via a GET request (you can GET the file's data, but that's not quite the same thing<sup>*</sup>).

Therefore, the form's method attribute should be POST, and it should also have the attribute `enctype` set to "[multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)" for absolute correctness.

```
<form action="/api/listtels" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

On the server side

- The route should accept POST requests only.
- The names of file inputs don't form part of `request.args`, so the membership test should be changed to test `request.files`.
- The uploaded file needs to be decoded and loaded into a buffer so that it can be handled by `csv.reader` (or it could be written to disk and then read back)

```
import io

@app.route('/api/listtels', methods=['POST'])
def ltels():

    tels = "ERROR" 
    ret = "ERROR"
    # Check if the file is loaded
    if 'tels' in request.files:
        tels = request.files['tels']
        ret = "tel\n"
    else:
        return("\'tels\' arg is needed")
    # Load decoded file data into a text buffer
    buf = io.StringIO(tels.read().decode('utf-8'))
    rows = csv.reader(buf,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rows, None)
    for row in rows:
        tel = row[0]
        tel = str(''.join(filter(str.isnumeric, tel)))
        if len(tel) == 11:
            ret = ret + tel + "\n"
        elif len(tel) == 13:
            ret = ret + "+" + tel + "\n"
return (ret)
```

<sup>*</sup> You could get the content via GET either by pasting the file's contents into an `<input type="textarea"...>` or manipulating the form data with javascript before sending it to the server.

Comment: Nice, gonna try it today! :D